# Magicavoxel: Change pivot point?

Tags: magicavoxel

I wonder if anyone knows if it is possible to change pivot point in Magicavoxel, and if so how it's done?

Comment: I'm not sure (so this is just a comment), but I don't think it's possible. I assume that you need to change the pivot point for rotations. I've played around with MagicaVoxel for a few evenings and it seems that in *World Editor* you can only rotate *Models* 90 deg on any axis and always around the center. In *Model Editor* you can rotate a selection of voxels any angel by writing "rot *[axis]* *[degree]*" in the *Console*. Seemingly always around the center of the selection. Why do you need this?

Comment: Ok thanks! Yes it is for rotation of canon turrets. The way they turn their "heads" look ridiculous when their center point is at the beginning of the barrel. I know i can do this in Blender and thats what i've been struggling with for some time. Wish i could have done this from the beginning in MV.

Comment: A trick can be to extend the model, so the point you want as pivot is in the middle of the model. Then rotate.

Comment: Yes thanks, that could have been the solution. Problem is that unless there is a way to shrink the model it is to big for that, since it already fills up the space provided.

Comment: I understand ... You might have reached MagicaVoxel's limitation. I'm using it to render 320x200 px images :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be done easily in MagicaVoxel. Go to World View and in the right menu select "Local Space". Exported obj will be at 0,0,0 when you import them in other software.

[image: local space]